# Does Intel vPro work via add-on NICs?

Tags: nic, sccm, intel, amt

We're currently using Dell OptiPlex workstations with the Intel vPro feature. A remote location is requiring their computers be connected via fibre for security reasons.  This will require us to install third-party FO NICs in the workstations.  My question is: will vPro OOB management (which we rely on) still work via this NIC?

Comment: if you get the intel nics with fc transievers yes

Comment: The intel NICs that come with the machines are LOM 1000BASE-TX.  This is the only option that Dell offers on these machines.  We are planning on purchasing Allied Telesis AT-2931SX/LC FO NICs to install on the PCI-x slot.

Comment: i'd say don't get the intel 1gb with sfp ports, then I think vpro applies still

Comment: please note that I don't know anything about vpro oob!

Comment: Thanks Tony.  What I'd really like to know is if an Intel NIC is REQUIRED, or will any NIC do?  Looking for someone with firsthand experience...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> vPro utilizes the integrated network adapter. Currently add-in cards
>   (fiber or otherwise) are not supported. However if they are willing to
>   use multiple adapters they could user a fiber add-in card for
>   high-bandwidth traffic, and a second wired connection for
>   manageability.

Source: http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/116384-intel-vpro-and-fiber-networks

I would try using a media converter from ethernet to fiber instead of another card if you want to connect via fiber and use vPro.

Comment: Correct. The vPro firmware needs to be able to communicate directly with the NIC, otherwise it wouldn't work when the machine wasn't fully booted into its OS.

Comment: +1 for doing the research.

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly the information I was looking for.  Many thanks!

Comment: Does that mean that security vulnerabilities related to vPro are not exploitable on third party NICs?